# Laravel Default Password Reset

Tags: laravel, configuration

I am using the default password reset. I would like to directly send the password reset link to the email address of the user. How am I going to do that?

It works using mailtrap.io. All the password reset link were emailed to my mailtrap account. However, I want to configure it in a way that it will send direct reset link to the user email address. Have tried different configuration but doesnt work.

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: @MateusJunges  MAIL_DRIVER=smtp  
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io  
MAIL_PORT=2525  
MAIL_USERNAME=(provided in mailtrap account)  
MAIL_PASSWORD=(provided in mailtrap account)  
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null

Comment: You just need to configure your .env with your email server. Then laravel will be able to send the reset link to the user who is trying to reset his password

Comment: @MateusJunges I tried this -> MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=xxxx@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=mypassword
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls

Comment: @MateusJunges got this error Connection to tcp://smtp.gmail.com:2525 Timed Out

Comment: Show your current SMTP config

Comment: @Ivan `'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),
'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.gmail.com'),
'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),
'from' => [
        'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'xxxx@gmail.com'),
        'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'Test'),
    ],
'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME', 'xxxx@gmail.com'),
  'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD', 'mypassword'),
'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
'markdown' => [
        'theme' => 'default',
`

Comment: @Ivan ` 'paths' => [
            resource_path('views/vendor/mail'),
        ],
    ],
'log_channel' => env('MAIL_LOG_CHANNEL'),
`

Comment: Now, I am getting "failed loading cafile stream: `C:\xampp\apache\bin\curl-ca-bundle.crt'"

Comment: Change `mail port` to 465. What is your `mail password` ? Is it your email password ? If yes, enable `2-step verification` and change it to `App password`.

Comment: I have tried downloading cacert.pem for this but it doesn't work.

Comment: @Ivan I tried to change to 465. I  already enabled 2-step verification. I am also using the App password as password of my email. Now, I am getting "Expected response code 220 but got an empty response".

Comment: Try this config `MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=[full gmail address]
MAIL_PASSWORD=[App Password obtained after two step verification]
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl`

Comment: I tried to add this to `$options['ssl']['verify_peer'] = FALSE;
        $options['ssl']['verify_peer_name'] = FALSE;  StreamBuffer,php under establishSocketConnection` and it finally works! Thank you so much for all your help :)